# Generate keyword symbols

Tags: elisp-macros, association-lists, keywords

I like to convert an alist within a macro call to a list of keyword symbols and corresponding values. E.g. given a macro `make-test` and an alist  `` `((a . 1)(b . "cool")) `` I want to obtain a call `(make-test :a 1 :b "cool")`. But with an arbitrary alist and arbitrary keyword symbols. How can that be done?

Generated a keyword symbol by `(intern ":a")` gives something that seems to be "equal" to `:a` in the sense of `(eq :a (intern ":a"))` being `t`. But I wasn't able to replace `:a` in the call by `(intern ":a")`...

Comment: "*Generated a keyword symbol by `(intern ":a")` gives something that **seem**s to be "equal" to `:a`*" -- what?  They are exactly the same value.

Comment: @shynur Yes, they have the same value. But `(make-test :a 1)` and `(make-test (intern ":a") 1)` do not! (And the later is causing an error!)

Comment: "*the later is causing an error*" -- Of course, because `make-test` is a *macro*.  I recommend reading the elisp manual or the elisp introduction to learn how *macro* works

Comment: Thanks for the hint @shynur . I did that but with that alone I wasn't enable to solve my problem! And with `:a` and `(intern ":a")` producing the same values neither...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(setq x '(
          (a . 1)
          (b . "cool")
          ))

(thread-last x
             (map-apply (pcase-lambda (k v)
                          (list (intern (format ":%s" k)) v)))
             (seq-mapcat #'identity)
             (cons 'make-test))

=> (make-test :a 1 :b "cool")
```

---

```lisp
(cl-loop for (k . v) in '(
                          (a . 1)
                          (b . "cool")
                          )
         appending (list (intern (format ":%s" k)) v) into y
         finally return (cons 'make-list y))

=> (make-test :a 1 :b "cool")
```

---

```lisp
(let ((x '(
           (a . 1)
           (b . "cool")
           )))
  (cons 'make-test
        (map-into
         (map-apply
          (lambda (k v)
            (cons (intern (format ":%s" k)) v))
          x)
         'plist)))

=> (make-test :a 1 :b "cool")
```

Comment: Ohhh great - that do the job!!! Thank you very much @mxnt!